# [unknown flag]Arangodb starter flag

Tags: arangodb

The flag cluster.system-replication-factor doesn't seem to be available in 3.4.2 , can anyone help with this
[arango starter command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9Pte.png)

We have tried the above command (click on the above link) in our arangoserver which runs with  arangodb 3.4.2 version

Comment: please provide any output /  commands in clear text instead of an attached image

Answer (score 0):

`--cluster.system-replication-factor` is an `arangod` option, it has to be passed to an ArangoDB Server.

https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/components/arangodb-server/options/#--clustersystem-replication-factor

> Options for `arangod` that are not supported by the starter (`arangodb`) can still be passed to the database servers using a pass through option. Every option that start with a pass through prefix is passed through to the commandline of one or more server instances.

https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/components/tools/arangodb-starter/options/#passing-through-other-database-options

Therefore the following option has to be specified:

```
arangodb --all.cluster.system-replication-factor=<uint32-value>
```